# Using Brackets in Anonymous Functions with Wildcards

Tags: scala, anonymous-function

I am currently learning Scala and am playing around with anonymous functions with `_` wildcards. This to me makes sense:

```
// Creates function operation(a, b, c) => a + (b / c)
var operation = (_:Double) + (_:Double) / (_:Double)
```

What I don't get is how to change `operation` to instead return `(a + b) / c`. None of these work:

```
// Attempting to create function operation(a, b, c) => (a + b) / c
var operation = ((_:Double) + (_:Double)) / (_:Double)
// error: value / is not a member of (Double, Double) => Double
var operation = ((_:Double) + (_:Double)).toDouble / (_:Double)
// error: value toDouble is not a member of (Double, Double) => Double
```

I'm guessing this is because putting `(_:Double) + (_:Double)` in brackets converts it to a `(Double, Double) => Double` function type. But then how do I actually change the order of operations? Is this even possible?

Comment: AFAIK is not possible, which is a good thing since that would stop you using the underscore syntax which is a good thing. That is probably one of the features more troubles cause to beginners and experts. It is only useful for small functions like `.map(_.foo)` or `.reduce(_ + _)`

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez It is *possible*, but yes, just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*. I avoid underscores as much as possible myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `+` is just another method in Scala, you can do this, calling it like another method using `.`:

```
var operation = (_: Double).+(_: Double) / (_: Double)
```

However, in my opinion, underscores should only be used for tiny, inconsequential functions (like in `foo.reduce(_ ^ _)`). If you need to use type ascriptions and play games with the syntax, it's likely better to turn that function into `(a: Double, b: Double, c: Double) => (a + b) / c`, or even better, make it a method. Another thing - in Scala, `val` (immutable) is preferred over `var` (mutable). Please use the former when possible.